# Rails 3: javascript to update single div after form submit with .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Hi I'm new using javascript with rails, and was hoping I could get some help. I have a like button that I use to like and unlike a post.

home.html:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.appreciations.
                          build(:liked_id => post.id),
                          :remote => true) do |f| %>
 <div><%= f.hidden_field :liked_id %></div>
 <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Like" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I use a js.erb file to render the unlike form after a post has been liked.

create.js.erb:

```
$("#like_form_<%= @post.id.to_s %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'users/unlike', :locals => {:post => @post})) %>")
```

I want to add a line that will update a div class="like-count<%= "_"+ post.id.to_s%>' afterwards in my view.

home.html:

```
<div class="like-count<%= "_"+ post.id.to_s%>">
  <%= user_post.likers.count.to_s %>
</div>
```

I have many posts that display in a feed, and I used the post.id.to_s in order to select the specific post like count to be updated. For testing I've targeted a specific post id=94 and I'm using the code below but it does not seem to work.

new create.js.erb:

```
$("#like_form_<%= @post.id.to_s %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'users/unlike', :locals => {:post => @post})) %>"
$(".like-count_94").reset();
```

Any input on the right function or where I'm going wrong would be great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your `like-count` div is unique, why not go with an ID versus a class?

```
$("#like-count").reset();
```

If it does need to be a class, and since you are grabbing the first one, you can use this syntax for the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abrefx3x/)):

```
$(".like-count").first().text('NEW TEXT/CONENT TO ADD');
```

I do not believe this is correct jQuery syntax:

```
$(".like-count").[0].reset();
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm trying to use .reset(), I have many different posts in a feed and need to use the .like-count as a class on every post. I need to use .like-count<%= @post.id.to_s %> in order to target the correct post to update the like count. I don't want to replace the div with text but instead just refresh the content to be updated showing a new like. For testing I am using $(".like-count_94").reset(); to target a specific post, however, clicking the like button it does not refresh the .like-count_94 div and show a new like number. I've updated the post to show my changes, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Just FYI, reset() - the method - is for forms and resetting them to their default state (i.e., clearing out the form fields). I do not believe it would work on a div. My sense is that you want either the text('')/html('') methods, which will replace the existing content or append('') which will add content to the div. You may just need to rebuild the div's content in your controller/.js.erb and then render it anew (i.e., with the text() or html() methods).

Comment: I've tried some thing with .html() and .reset() but I am still quite lost as to how to refresh a div, I've even tried creating a separate partial to replace the partial but I can't get the 'post' :locals to work :(

Comment: Long story short, `reset()` will not work for what you want. It's simply to reset the form fields to their original/default state and values. .html() or .text() is what you need. There really isn't a way to 'refresh' your div's content. You have to rebuild it and add it to the DOM in your .js.erb.